# How to remove previous stack of UIView after adding a new one?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, stack

I want to add a new subview every time I swipe right, but then it will stack many times if I do not destroy the previous subview. I know how to remove it, but I am struggling with the logic of how to remove it only after I add a new one.

I have tried this:

```
    var view1: UIView?
    var view2: UIView?
    var ctrl = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1?.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))
    }

    func addView(){
        if let test1 = view1, let test2 = view2 {
            if ctrl == true {
                test1.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))
                test2.removeFromSuperview()
                ctrl = false
            }else{
                test2.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))
                test1.removeFromSuperview()
                ctrl = true
            }   
        }
    }

    @IBAction func swipeRight(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Right")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.view.layer.backgroundColor = .black
        }){(isFinished) in
            self.addView()
            //I am hoping that after this the view stack before will be removed
        }
    }
```

the Class CustomView is this:

```
var primaryColors: [UIColor] = [
    .red,
    .yellow,
    .blue]

class CustomView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        primaryColors.shuffle()

        let leftRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.size.width/2, height: rect.size.height)
        primaryColors[0].set()
        guard let leftContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        leftContext.fill(leftRect)

        let rightRect = CGRect(x: rect.size.width/2, y: 0, width: rect.size.width/2, height: rect.size.height)
        primaryColors[1].set()
        guard let rightContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        rightContext.fill(rightRect)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should add the view in the second completion handler but remove the previous ones in the first completion handler. Give it a try.

Comment: What did you mean by second completion handler and first completion handler? @Mihir

Comment: In `UIView.animate()`, you are using 2 closures or simply the first block and the second block. Also give [this](https://medium.com/@nimjea/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178) article a read. Its about completion handlers.

Comment: @Mihir I see what you are suggesting, but I don't know why it won't add then remove, it's just keep removing the view, I was hoping it will add a view first and then remove previous, but since the view does not change I take that it's just keep removing instead of adding it first.

Comment: In your code `view1?.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))` this line adds a view to view1 and you have no reference to the view you are adding. You should first store the view you add like `view3 = CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds)` so that later you can remove view3. Also your `view1` actually never gets added If I am right because to add `view1` you need to add like `view.addSubview(view1)` first.

Comment: Maybe if you provide some more detail about your issue, a better solution can be given.

Comment: @Mihir I am so confuse right now.... and there i've provided some more details about the CustomView i've been using

Comment: I will make some changes to my answer, maybe then it may help.

Comment: Check the answer now, it may help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not that good at swift, but till what I understand your problem, this should solve it.
And if it doesn’t, I am pretty sure someone better in swift will answer it in a more better way.

Every `ViewController` has a base `view` which you can access like `view.method()`.

You add a subview to an existing view.

Supposing you want to add a new UIView named view1.

First you initialise it like,

`view1 = UIView(frame: view.bounds)`

Now to make it appear on screen, do like,

`view.addSubview(view1)`

This line would add `view1` as subview of `view`.

Also now `view1` is on top of `view`. So now when you touch your screen it is the `view1` you are accessing. 
So the next time you swipe right, the gesture recogniser should be on `view1`.

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRightAction))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right

view1.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

This is how you will add gesture of right swipe to view1.

Now when you right swipe on screen, `swipeRightAction()` will get called.

You can remove this `view1` from super view like,

`view1.removeFromSuperView()`

Now view1 is gone and now you can add `view2` by similar process as we added `view1`.

See the following code, it may be relatable.

```
//The old view that has to be replaced
    var viewToBeRemoved : UIView!

    //The new view that will replace the previous one
    var viewToBeAdded   : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        replaceWithNewSwipableSubview()


    }


    func replaceWithNewSwipableSubview()
    {
        viewToBeAdded = UIView(frame: view.bounds)

        //New view being added should have a gesture so that next time
        //it need to be replaced we can swipe on it
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRightAction))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right

        viewToBeAdded.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

            //This will be animated

            if self.viewToBeRemoved != nil{

                //As there is no subview the very first time this func is called

                self.viewToBeRemoved.removeFromSuperview()

            }

            //Because next time it will be the view to be removed
            self.viewToBeRemoved = self.viewToBeAdded


        }) { (isFinished) in

            //This block gets executed only after
            //the block above has completed
            self.view.addSubview(self.viewToBeAdded)


            //view is the default base view of a ViewController

        }
    }



    @objc func swipeRightAction() {

        replaceWithNewSwipableSubview()

    }
```

In your code `view1?.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))` this line adds a view to view1 and you have no reference to the view you are adding. You should first store the view you add like `view3 = CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds)` so that later you can remove view3. Also your `view1` actually never gets added If I am right because to add `view1` you need to add like `view.addSubview(view1)` first.

Although possibly a better solution can be suggested if you tell us what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: with a view adjustment of the code above, it actually works. but now another problem appear, I cannot animate the background color

Comment: [Animate UIView background color swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383678/animate-uiview-background-color-swift) and [UIView.animate syntax for swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991822/whats-the-swift-3-animatewithduration-syntax). These shall help you with coloraturas animations. I can only help you if you exactly tell what you want to make by doing this? Do you want to swap UIViews getting a different colour each time?

Answer (score 0):

It might not working. In your if condition of addSubview method you are using: 
`if let test1 = view1, let test2 = view2` which check that both `view1` and `view2` are not `nil`.
This must be failing because you only initialized `view1` in `viewDidLoad()`:
`view1?.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))`. So in above if condition `view2` must be nil and hence it will evaluate to `false`.

Try placing your if condition like this: 
`if let test1 = view1 || let test2 = view2` (check for syntax if it gives error, `ll` will give error in if condition with let). And let me know if it doesn't work. Try below code:

```
if((self.view1 != nil) || (self.view2 != nil){
    if ctrl == true {
        self.view1?.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))
        self.view2?.removeFromSuperview()
        ctrl = false
    }else{
        self.view2?.addSubview(CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds))
        self.view1?.removeFromSuperview()
        ctrl = true
    }   
 }
```

Comment: I don't know why but cannot use "||" on if condition

Comment: Knew it, but haven't got my MacSystem around. Updated answer, give it a try.